# RHEL 8.6 WebSphere 9 UI issues

Tags: websphere, redhat

I have been trying to install Websphere onto a VM running RHEL 8.6 and 8.5 but after several attempts and multiple VMs I`ve has no luck and keep running into the same issue.

The following screenshot is what I keep running into:

[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDLrD.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8lVA.png

As you can see from the images the UI is broken and cannot be used for its intended purpose. There is no way (which I could find) to resize the windows or scroll.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on VM RHEL 8.6 and able to resize the Profile Tool fine. It may be your VNC viewer problem.

I have used this to configure my VM  for RHEL vnc.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-configure-vnc-server-red-hat-enterprise-linux-8

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by disabling gnome 3.0 and revert it back to gnome 2.0